# php mysql error with not uploading the data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code, no error is thrown but the data is not inserted to the table and no table is created, can you please tell me where i am going wrong?

Cheers in advance :)

DB_Functions.php

```
private $db;

     // constructor
     function __construct() {
         require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
         // connecting to database
         $this->db = new DB_Connect();
         $this->db->connect();
     }

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

 public function storeUnit($email, $units, $maint, $attent, $done) {
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $con);

        $format = 'Y-m-d G:i:s';
        $date = date($format);
        $result = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $email( Units VARCHAR(10), Finish VARCHAR(20), Attent VARCHAR(200), Maint VARCHAR(200), created_at VARCHAR(30))",$con);
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$email'(Units, Finish, Attent, Maint, created_at) VALUES('$units', '$done', '$attent', '$maint', '$date')");
        return true;
}
```

Comment: what the error are you getting?

Comment: im not getting one, plainly the information is not being incerted into the table and the table is not being created

Comment: @Nicholas remove the single quote around the name of the table `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $email ...` [click this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06dfb) for example. as you can see the query was successfully built. try to modify it by adding single quote ion tableName and it won't build.

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't work tho :(

Comment: @Nicholas you mean the table was not created even if you remove the single quote?

Comment: Yes, i still dont get any table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using ` instead of ' for tablename

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$email`(Units, Finish, Attent, Maint, created_at) VALUES('$units', '$done', '$attent', '$maint', '$date')");
```

Edit : Try looking if your database uses InnoDB, you may use transactional mode... so you must commit changes if autocommit is disabled

Comment: Your AWESOME!!!!!!!!! It works now!!! Thank you heaps!!!! I will accept your answer when i'm allowed to :)

Comment: You can accept the answer still just click on tick(Accept Sign) below rank of this answer

Answer (score 3):

this is my first post, but I think you've bad architecture of code or bad OOP design  for your application, but the problem is you use wrong quotes to create table and insert row.
You need to use these symbols to quote names "`" for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `table name` ....
INSERT INTO `table name` ....
```

So I think that you have to think for your security of code, use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to php and mysql so excuse my bad sytax